# How to swap jquery css on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with Up and Down button in all the rows and i want to move rows onclick of up/down in respective directions in table. I am able to do it but the issue is i have a style sheet for alternate rows which i do not want to move along with row movement. But current function move css also which looks very wearied on the page. Can someone please let me know how can i stop moving CSS. My code is below -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }
    });
});
```

I have to check if moving row has come css then it should be stripped and assigned to new row.

Comment: How are you keeping track of the difference between odd and even rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wondering if this seem a bit acceptable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var new_class='';
    var neigbour_class='';
    if (row.hasClass('odd')) {
       new_class='even';
       neighbour_class='odd';
    }
    else {
       new_class='odd';
       neighbour_class='even';
    }
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        row.removeClass().addClass(new_class);
        row.prev().removeClass().addClass(neighbour_class);
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
        row.removeClass().addClass(new_class);
        row.next().removeClass().addClass(neighbour_class);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Yes this works with a small improvement - <code> row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        row.removeClass().addClass(new_class);
        row.prev().removeClass().addClass(neighbour_class);</code>

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, set up your styles like this:

```
        tr:nth-child(even) {  }

        tr:nth-child(odd) {  }
```

Now when you move rows around, the styles won't get messed up.  Just note that this will likely not work in ancient browsers.  If you have to support IE7 ish, your might have to do a bit more work.

Comment: I think this is not possible in every browser. A other jquery solution would be to use the addClass and removeClass methods on your row element

Comment: @Grrbrr404 indeed.  I added an edit to that affect.  So is IE 8 and down gone yet?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }

        $("table tr:odd").removeClass('even odd').addClass('odd');
        $("table tr:even").removeClass('even odd').addClass('even');
    });
});
```

read [odd selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [even selector](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)